# 2.8 Can’t connect compositor nodes

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

having moved to Blender 2.8 I’ve gone to use the Compositor for the first time and then realised I can’t drag node connections from one node to another node. Like here…

https://gph.is/g/E1qmpAD

But I can drag connections to nodes in the Shader Editor.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Judging from what we can see in the gif this is a bug. Try restarting your machine and Blender, disable addons, test if your problem is solved with a different version of 2.8 (or 2.81, 2.82). If not write a Bug report with the proper template.

Comment: Are you using a mouse or trackpad.

Answer (score 1):

Actually in the end it seemed to be because I had 2 Compositor viewport windows opened at the same time.

Weird, thanks anyhow.